How to set configfs when buildroot system computer starts
I'm using embedded linux, buildroot. I want my Linux device to be recognized by the host directly as a mass storage device when I boot it up.
My current progress: I have compiled the mass storage module and written the basic configFS script. After I boot up, I can manually use the script to change the Linux device to mass storage.
But I didn't know how to operate configFS so that I could have my board recognized as a mass storage device at boot time without using a script manually. (Setting the script to automatically execute on startup is not what I want, because the host will tell you that you have inserted a new USB device.)
How do I set configFS or other options so that my device starts up as mass storage?
Also, can you give me some information about how to use configFS? I can't find a good tutorial for configFS.

I'm confused. It sounds like you want something to happen automatically at boot time (without manually running a script). But you also say you don't want this to automatically happen on startup. Can you clarify the question?

Sorry, let me explain again: Based on my existing experiments, if I execute my script to set up configFS at boot time, I have the following two-step shell command
echo "" > UDC  # Unbind the UDC first, otherwise it will not be bound later
echo "ffb00000.usb" > UDC  # Bind the UDC I set up earlier

When I do these two steps, windows first tells me that the USB device is inserted, then unplugs the device, and inserts it again.
I don't want windows to pop up these prompts, I want to boot it directly to the mass_storage device. I guess I might need to write a little into configFS.
